# SUSY $SU(5)$ GUT chiral adjoint repersentations

Tags: supersymmetry, higgs, representation-theory, chirality, grand-unification

when you have a chiral superfield in the adjoint representation in your theory (i.e the Higgs $\Sigma_{24}$ in $SU(5)$), you can write it as a $5\times5$ Matrix: $(\Sigma_{24})_i^j=\Sigma^a (t^a)_i^j$ (sum over a), where the $t^a$ are the generatorns of the $SU(5)$.

My question is: is it possible that the $\Sigma_a$ are real, or do they have to be complex for $SU(5)$ SUSY GUT?

I'm asking because some steps in the calculation of the minimum (vev) seem to need real $\Sigma_a$'s, since that would make $\Sigma_{24}$ Hermitian. But on the other side I'm not sure if real scalars would make problems with supersymmetry (degrees of freedom).

thanks

---

Update:

The problem with real $\Sigma_a$ is the following:

Suppose you want to write down the superfield $S$ in components. For one complex scalar $\Phi$ it would look as follows: $S=\Phi+\sqrt{2} \theta \Psi+\theta\theta F$. Looking at the degrees of freedome on-shell $\rightarrow dof(\Phi)=2, dof(\Psi)=2,dof(F)=0$

Now looking at the adjoint representation of $\Sigma$, wich is a 24-dimesional multiplett ($\Sigma_1,...,\Sigma_{24}$)(this are the $\Sigma_a$ from above, (btw. $\Sigma_a=\Sigma^a$, sorry for mixing notation)). Now each field in this supermultiplett has to be a superfield, like above $\Sigma_a=\Phi_a+\sqrt{2} \theta \Psi_a+\theta\theta F_a$. Counting now the degress of freedome reveals the problem: $\rightarrow dof(\Phi_a)=1, dof(\Psi_a)=2,dof(F_a)=0$. That shows that the fermionic dof. are not equal to the bosonic dof. wich contradicts SUSY.

Edit:

- $i,j$ in $\Sigma_i^j$ are matrix indices and run from 1 to 5.
- $a$ in $t^a$ and $\Sigma^a$ runs from 1 to 24 (24 = dimension of adjoint representation of $SU(5)$)

Comment: Could you explain your notation in a little more detail?  For instance, to what are the characters $j$, $i$, and $a$ referring?  It would help the reader (though I imagine Susy crowd probably understands this already)...

Comment: sure I added a bit of detail ;)

Comment: @Johnny1557, are you asking that is it possible to choose Higgs in the adjoint representation $SU(5)$ to be real?

Comment: Yes. I know that it is possible in non-susy models, but I'm not sure about SUSY. Since Wikipedia tells me "For particles that are real scalars (such as an axion), there is a fermion superpartner as well as a second, real scalar field",(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superpartner). But what if I have 24, real scalars (i.e the adjoint of $SU(5)$), do I need another 24 ???

Comment: your question is edited. please check whether it reflects your actual query or not.

Comment: Yeah, i checked the edit suggestions before I approved them ;)

Comment: I have given "an" answer to your question. Have a look on it.

Answer (score 0):

In  any theory in  which supersymmetry  is  relevant down to  1 TeV,  the  supersymmetric  partners  of  the  leptons  are  spinless  bosons  with  the  right  $SU(2)\times U(1)$ properties  to  be  Higgs  mesons.  However,  for  various  reasons,  they  cannot  be.

The most  serious  objection  to  using  the  lepton  partners  as  Higgs  mesons  is  that  the partners  of  the  charge  $-1/3$  quarks  then  mediate  baryon  number  changing  interactions.  To  eliminate  this  difficulty, the  Higgs  doublets  must  be  part  of  a  different $SU(5)$  multiplet  whose  color  triplet  components  are  superheavy.  To  ensure  that 
baryon  number  is  conserved  except  by  the  usual  $SU(5)$  baryon  number  changing interactions,  we require  that the Higgs multiplets couple to pairs of quark  and lepton multiplets  just  as in  the usual $SU(5)$  model.

This in turns saying that taking the representations of Higgs in the adjoint (for real) just like minimal $SU(5)$, is acceptable.

Comment: Ok, so i think you are talking about the two higgses, that are used for susy breaking, and refer to the doublet triplet splitting problem right? But I 'm talking about the Higgs that is used for GUT breaking, which already is in the adjoint representation.

Comment: Consider the case that one have to show that $SU(5)$ SUSY GUT in anomaly free. Which representation of Higgs you gonna take, in order to make sure the anomaly cancellation? Answer of this question will fix  the possible representations (real, pseudo real or complex) of particle.

Comment: I did not think about anamalies but you`re right, one has to take that into account also...
I will update the question to show you where I think the problem is...

Comment: If you find the answer useful then up vote it.

Comment: Another point is, anomaly coefficient for the adjoint representation of  $SU(N)$ gauge group is zero.

Comment: I'm afraid I do not know enough about anomalies to find your answer helpful. And it seems for me that you are giving arguments if the representation can be adjoint or not, but I have a adjoint representation for sure. My question is if the fields can be taken real (see UPDATE in the original qestion)

Comment: It does not matter whether you are dealing with "Ordinary QFT" or supersymmetric QFT, anomaly (due to gauge invariance) cancellations is a fundamental requirement. If a theory has local anomaly, it become non-renormalizable.

Comment: Well as i said, i do not know much about anomalies and do not want to consider them here. They are from my point of view a completely different part of the model building process. My concerns are about the difficulties according to the degrees of freedom, mentioned in my question above.